# Как выбрать option в select

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="sel">
    <select id="select" data-ids="1">
      <option class="test1" data-id="1">Selection 1</option>
      <option class="test2" data-id="2">Selection 2</option>
      <option class="test3" data-id="3">Selection 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

У меня есть код html. Как мне выбрать data-id у option при клике? Мучаюсь два часа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var eSelect = document.getElementById('select');
  eSelect.onchange = function() {
    var nOm = eSelect.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log(nOm);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sel">
  <select id="select" data-ids="1">
    <option class="test1" data-id="1">Selection 1</option>
    <option class="test2" data-id="2">Selection 2</option>
    <option class="test3" data-id="3">Selection 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое дружище, если б ты знал как мне помог!!!